# c++ no-op function on null pointer

Tags: c++

In short, the question is: if I call a no-op function on a null pointer is that UB?

Roughly speaking, I want to make a lightweight class which just becomes no-ops depending on build flags. For example:

```
class RealObject {
  void foo() { /* do something real*/ }
};

class DummyObject {
  inline void foo() {}
};

#ifdef DO_REAL
RealObject* obj = new Object();
#else
DummyObject* obj = nullptr;
#endif

obj->foo();
```

My gut tells me in the case where DummyObject gets used it violates something in the standard (don't what exactly what) but since foo() is no-op in practice it still could work as expected.

Can someone clarify the rules in this situation? thanks

Comment: In short and formally? Yes. Practically? I don't know an implementation that does something nasty with this.

Comment: Why do you need to invoke anything if you are using macro anyway?

Comment: @Slava This is a just a toy example to get the point across.

Comment: If you want sometime like to to become pretty close to a no-op but remain defined behavior you might consider making the `DummyObject` variation point to a statically allocated singleton: `static DummyObject do_singleton; ... ; DummyObject* obj = &do_singleton;`. In optimization the compiler should elide all calls, the linker might even be able to remove the do-nothing object as well.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why did you came up with this solution? _What are you trying to achieve?_

Comment: You can create a thin wrapper for a pointer to `RealObject` and use it instead.